# Chord identification (dim7)

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-theory

[image]

As you can see I've marked a viiDim7 chord.

My question is because of lack of bB on 1st and 2nd beat and by knowing that it is a key note for C#dim7 chord

can we consider it as just a dim chord and bB as a **auxiliary note** ?

And also  the **bass** note D is not exists in C#dim7 , how can it be analyzed?

Extra info:

The next bar is the same
And after that we have Dminor chord

Answer (score 5):

The D is a tonic pedal - a continual feature of this piece.

Bars 3 and 5 are alternative harmonisations of the same melody.   The first half of bar 5 could be labelled viidim, the second half becomes viidim7.   An overall analysis of viidim7 is not unreasonable.

After one note, all we know is D.  After two notes, is it D(maj7)?  After three, perhaps it's going to be C♯m/D?    As each note occurs, the overall picture becomes clearer.   I've no problem with analysing the entire bar as if all the notes were on the first beat!   If you want to give the two halves of the bar different labels - well, that's fine too!

Comment: I think one chord for the bar is fine too, especially if what would be an added figure (like this 7) doesn't change the bass or imply a new tonic.

Comment: With pedal note, it could be a polychord as well... Bach wasn't following the rules, he was making them.